# Cauchy's Functional Equation $ f ( x + y ) = f ( x ) + f ( y ) $ with the Additional Assumption $ f \left( x ^ { n + 1 } \right) = x ^ n f ( x ) $

Tags: functional-equations

> Assume that $ n $ is a given positive integer. Determine all functions $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that
> $$ f ( x + y ) = f ( x ) + f ( y ) \tag 0 \label 0 $$
> forall $ x , y \in \mathbb R $, and
> $$ f \left( x ^ { n + 1 } \right) = x ^ n f ( x ) \tag 1 \label 1 $$
> for all $ x \in \mathbb R $.

I've recently encountered two posts ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831461/continuous-functions-f-that-satisfy-f1-2-and-f-leftx2y2-right-xfx/3838429#3838429) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130648/finding-a-family-of-functions-with-the-property-f-leftx4y-right-x3fx/3837944#3837944)) where the problem was somehow similar to the above one; one was in fact equivalent to the above question for $ n = 3 $, and the other one was similar to the case $ n = 1 $. While those posts asked for solutions with additional regularity assumptions like continuity and differentiability, I found out that \eqref{0} and \eqref{1} themselves were enough for showing that all solutions are of the form $ f ( x ) = a x $ for some constant $ a \in \mathbb R $, and posted answers to them not using the additional regularity conditions.

Let's consider the case $ n = 2 $. Letting $ a = f ( 1 ) $ and using \eqref{1} together with \eqref{0} and its well-known consequences, we have
$$ \left( x ^ 2 + 2 x + 1 \right) \big( f ( x ) + a \big) = ( x + 1 ) ^ 2 f ( x + 1 ) = f \left( ( x + 1 ) ^ 3 \right) \\
= f \left( x ^ 3 \right) + f \left( 3 x ^ 2 \right) + f ( 3 x ) + f ( 1 ) = 3 f \left( x ^ 2 \right) + \left( x ^ 2 + 3 \right) f ( x ) + a \text . \tag 2 \label 2 $$
Similarly, by calculating $ f \left( ( x - 1 ) ^ 3 \right) $ in two different ways, we get
$$ \left( x ^ 2 - 2 x + 1 \right) \big( f ( x ) - a \big) = - 3 f \left( x ^ 2 \right) + \left( x ^ 2 + 3 \right) f ( x ) - a \text . \tag 3 \label 3 $$
Adding \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} (and dividing by $ 2 $) we get
$$ \left( x ^ 2 + 1 \right) f ( x ) + 2 a x = \left( x ^ 2 + 3 \right) f ( x ) \text , $$
which shows that $ f ( x ) = a x $.

For $ n = 1 $, the problem can be solved more easily, as we only need to consider $ f \left( ( x + 1 ) ^ 2 \right) $ (see [my answer to the related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831461/continuous-functions-f-that-satisfy-f1-2-and-f-leftx2y2-right-xfx/3838429#3838429)). For $ n = 3 $, the "$ f \left( ( x \pm 1 ) ^ 2 \right) $ technique" above gives us an equation containing $ f \left( x ^ 2 \right) $ and $ f ( x ) $, and then we can use this equation and continue similar to the case of $ n = 1 $ (see [my answer to the related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130648/finding-a-family-of-functions-with-the-property-f-leftx4y-right-x3fx/3837944#3837944)).

It seems that as \eqref{1} takes the multiplicative structure of $ \mathbb R $ into account in a very specific way, it could be true than for any $ n $ the solutions are linear. But the problem with my above approach for $ n \ge 4 $ is that using the expressions for $ f \left( ( x \pm 1 ) ^ { n + 1 } \right) $, there will be more than one term of the form $ f ( x ^ m ) $ ($ m > 1 $) in the equation, and I don't know how to handle that. Is there any other way to get around this problem? Or is there in fact a nonlinear solution for larger $ n $?

Comment: An obvious idea would be to use $f( (x\pm k)^{n+1})$ for more than one $k$.

Comment: The only solutions to Cauchy's functional equation are $f(x) = ax$, and the other "wild" solutions that exist by the axiom of choice but there couldn't possibly be formulas for. By the way, the most obvious way to me to get from (1) to $f(x) = ax$ to use it to show continuity of $f$ at zero, which by (0) implies continuity everywhere and forces $f(x) = ax$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general thing of what you're asking is the following:

> If $f$ is a Cauchy function and $f(x^n)=x^kf(x^{n-k})$ for positive integers $n,k$, then $f$ is linear.

The proof is as follows:
Put $x\rightarrow x+q$ where $q$ is an arbitrary rational number. Then let's expand $f((x+q)^n)$:
First of all (although it is clear) note that:

> For a Cauchy function $f$, $f(qx)=qf(x)$ and $f(q)=qf(1)$ hold for all rational numbers $q$.

$$f((x+q)^n)=(x+q)^kf((x+q)^{n-k})$$
$$f((x+q)^n)=f\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{t}\cdot x^tq^{n-t}}\bigg)=\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{t}\cdot q^{n-t}f(x^t)}$$
On the other hand:
$$(x+q)^kf((x+q)^{n-k})=\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k}{\binom{k}{i}\cdot x^iq^{k-i}}\bigg)\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}{\binom{n-k}{j}\cdot x^jq^{n-k-j}}\bigg)$$
So finally:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{t}\cdot q^{n-t}f(x^t)}=\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k}{\binom{k}{i}\cdot x^iq^{k-i}}\bigg)\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}{\binom{n-k}{j}\cdot q^{n-k-j}f(x^j)}\bigg)$$
Now assume these two as polynomials on $q$. Because these two polynomials are equal to each other for each rational number $q$, they are also equal for all real values $q$. Hence, the coefficients are equal in both sides.
By checking the coefficients of $q^{n-1}$ we'll have:
$$nq^{n-1}f(x)=q^k(n-k)q^{n-k-1}f(x)+kxq^{k-1}\cdot q^{n-k}f(1)$$
By simplifying this:
$$nf(x)=(n-k)f(x)+kxf(1)$$
And finally $f(x)=xf(1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

P.S. The following is also true (the proof is very much like this so please do it yourself:

> If $f$ is a Cauchy function and $f(x^n)=x^kf(x)^{n-k}$ for positive integers $k,n$, then $f$ is linear.